# Report Builder 3.0 Sum Value String

Tags: string, sum, report, builder

I have a dataset with an `int` field that is formatted in string. How can I sum that field? I am not able to change the source.

I have tried

```
=sum(value(Fields!String.Value))
=sum(int(Fields!String.Value))
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CInt()` function and you also need to provide a DataSet where your Field is.

```
=Sum(CInt(Fields!String.Value),"DataSet")
```